How to Ensure Chrome Proxy Extension Settings are Updated When Using --user-data-dir in Python?
I'm using a Python script with undetected_chromedriver to set up a Chrome proxy using a custom extension. The script works as expected initially, but when I try to change the proxy settings and rerun the script, the old proxy settings seem to persist due to caching in the Chrome profile.
import os
import time
import shutil
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

class ChromeProxy:

    def __init__(
        self,
        host: str,
        port: int,
        username: str = "",
        password: str = ""
    ):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def get_path(self) -> str:
        return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "proxy_extension")

    def create_extension(
        self,
        name: str = "Chrome Proxy",
        version = "1.0.0"
    ) -> str:
        proxy_folder = self.get_path()
        os.makedirs(proxy_folder, exist_ok=True)

        # Generate manifest (set extension name and version)
        manifest = ChromeProxy.manifest_json
        manifest = manifest.replace("<ext_name>", name)
        manifest = manifest.replace("<ext_ver>", version)

        # Write manifest to extension directory
        with open(f"{proxy_folder}/manifest.json", "w") as f:
            f.write(manifest)

        # Generate JavaScript code (replace placeholders)
        js = ChromeProxy.background_js
        js = js.replace("<proxy_host>", self.host)
        js = js.replace("<proxy_port>", str(self.port))
        js = js.replace("<proxy_username>", self.username)
        js = js.replace("<proxy_password>", self.password)

        # Write JavaScript code to extension directory
        with open(f"{proxy_folder}/background.js", "w") as f:
            f.write(js)

        return proxy_folder

    manifest_json = """
    {
        "version": "<ext_ver>",
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "name": "<ext_name>",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "storage",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestAuthProvider"
        ],
        "host_permissions": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "background": {
            "service_worker": "background.js"
        },
        "minimum_chrome_version": "22.0.0"
    }
    """

    background_js = """
    var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
            singleProxy: {
                scheme: "http",
                host: "<proxy_host>",
                port: parseInt("<proxy_port>")
            },
            bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };

    chrome.proxy.settings.set({
        value: config,
        scope: "regular"
    }, function() {});

    function callbackFn(details) {
        return {
            authCredentials: {
                username: "<proxy_username>",
                password: "<proxy_password>"
            }
        };
    }

    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        callbackFn, {
            urls: ["<all_urls>"]
        },
        ['blocking']
    );
    """

# Initialize proxy settings
proxy = ChromeProxy(
    host="00.000.000.000",
    port=5868,
    username="test",
    password="test"
)

# Create the extension
extension_path = proxy.create_extension()

# Set Chrome options with the proxy extension
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=D:\Telegram Farm\bot\chrome_profiles\profile4")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")  # Use 'Default' or specify another profile
options.add_argument(f"--load-extension={extension_path}")

# Initialize the Chrome driver with the proxy and profile options
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

# Open the website
driver.get("https://2ip.ua/ru/")

# Wait for a few seconds
time.sleep(5)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()


I need to ensure that the new proxy settings are applied correctly each time I run the script
